# Spring Integration http inbound gateway mapped response headers - being duplicated?

Tags: content-type, spring-integration

I'm trying to set the content-type of a response for an image host service, so I have an http:inbound-gateway that looks like this:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="receiveChannel"
                          reply-channel="responseChannel"
                          path="/profile/photo"
                          mapped-response-headers="Content-Type"
                          message-mappers="messageConverterList"
                          supported-methods="GET"/>
```

... and a service activator that looks like this:

```
<int:service-activator 
    input-channel="receiveChannel" 
    output-channel="imageResponseChannel"
    expression="@profileService.getPhoto(payload.userId)"/>
```

... which returns a byte[] of jpeg image data. I have a header enricher that looks like this:

```
<int:header-enricher
    input-channel="imageResponseChannel"
    output-channel="responseChannel">
    <int:header
        name="Content-Type"
        expression="'image/jpeg'"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

But when I run the project I get a response with headers like this:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9uw5c136fia6s9ivxgivy1yc;Path=/
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 6563
< Server: Jetty(8.1.3.v20120416)
```

Notice that the content-type is repeated, but it's my understanding that mapped-response-headers should grab the headers from the message, and not determining it from the payload.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

*EDIT: I changed the inbound-gateway to reference a custom message-mappers below, but I still get the same result.

```
<util:list id="messageConverterList">
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
            <list><value>image/jpeg</value></list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</util:list>
```

*EDIT 2: Turns out it should have been message-converters, but I didn't get an error because I modified the file in target and not src. I made the correction and this is the output I get:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Content-Length: 209582
< Server: Jetty(6.1.10)
```

Better, but not perfect. Here's a simple reproduction project of the issue: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/92800052/http.tar.gz

you can run it with

```
mvn package jetty:run
```

and see the output with

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/http/photo > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

By default several HttpMessageConverters (from the core Spring Web lib) are registered for the inbound gateway. One of those is ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter, and it's default content-type is "application/octet-stream". Could you try setting the "message-converters" attribute on your gateway so that it references a List-typed bean that contains a single instance of ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter (e.g. you can use util:list) - rather than relying on the default converters, and then on that instance set the supportedMediaTypes property to 'image/jpeg'.

AFAIK, the ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter should not try setting a Content-Type header if one is already present (i.e. from the mapped response headers), but I just want to check and see if that change does indeed bypass the duplication.

Also, can you please let us know what version of Spring Integration you are using?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Sure. I'm using 2.1.3.RELEASE. The code I added is in the EDIT, along with the result (since I can't add code in a comment).

Comment: Can you try one more thing... in the header-enricher can you use lowercase instead of uppercase for "content-type"?

Comment: I just tried lower casing content-type of the header enricher, and then in the gateway with the same result every time (duplicated Content-Type HTTP header). I can create a sanitized version of the project and post it on github. Do you think that would help?

Comment: Yes, please do. That should help us to debug and find out where the duplicate header is being added.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this. Turns out I modified the file in target instead of src, so the mods I made didn't count once I repackaged. The content-type is still repeated, but it's the same value. The question has been updated. I'll comment with a dropbox link to the sanitized project.

Comment: Created a bug report. If this isn't a bug feel free to cancel it. https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-2680